# How to get the placeholder and the text to begin from the start of the textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**How do I get the placeholder/text at the start top-left of the textarea? It is at the centre right now.**

```css
.input-textarea {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  resize: vertical;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<label class="comment-label" for="comments">Comments</label>
<input type="textarea" name="comments" id="comments" class="input-textarea" placeholder="Enter your comments here..." required>
```

*OUTPUT*

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the `::placeholder` css rule

Comment: Also [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)

Comment: input does not have a type called textarea see the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
textarea.comment {
    height: 59px;
    resize: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-left: 22px;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="comment" placeholder="Enter your comments here..." spellcheck="false"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change your HTML to using the textarea element it will work as you want it to. Input elements are not intended to be used that way.

````
<label class="comment-label" for="comments">Comments</label>
<textarea name="comments" id="comments" class="input-textarea" placeholder="Enter your comments here..." required></textarea>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you.

```css
.input-textarea {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  resize: vertical;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative;
}

.placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.input-textarea:focus~.placeholder,
.input-textarea:valid~.placeholder {
  display: none;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<label class="comment-label" for="comments">Comments</label>
<div class="parent"><input type="textarea" name="comments" id="comments" class="input-textarea" placeholder="" required>
  <span class="placeholder">Enter your comments here...</span></div>
```

Comment: There is no input type="textarea" in the spec.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest would be replace input element with text area element. If still you want achieve with input element you can try to style the placeholder pseudo-element by adjusting the position according to your need

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
       position:relative;
       top:-35px;
    }

    :-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
       position:relative;
       top:-35px;  
    }

    ::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
       position:relative;
       top:-35px; 
    }

    :-ms-input-placeholder {  
       position:relative;
       top:-35px; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to `vertical-align` your `placeholde`r and the carret to type  your comment, you may use a `contenteditable` `div` + `flex`.

here is an example of the idea :

```css
label {
  display: block;
}

.flxbx {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: solid;
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

.flxbx,
label {
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0.5em;
}

.flxbx:empty::before {
  content: attr(data-placeholder);
}

body {
  background: #222;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<label>Comments</label>
<div class="flxbx" data-placeholder="Enter your comment here.." contenteditable></div>
```